# Trigger event when iframe src is changed (not loaded)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I can trigger an event when an iframe is loaded using the below or `.on( "load", handler )`.

```
$( "#myIframe" ).load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

I will be changing the iframe src using something like `$('#myIframe').attr('newurl.html')`

Can I trigger an event when the src of the iframe is changed but not yet loaded?

Obviously I could set a flag right when I change it, but I am doing it multiple places, and it would be easier to maintain if it occurred on an event.  My purpose is to disable other various events between the time when the iframe src was changed, and will be using the `load()` method to restore the events when it is loaded.

Comment: Could use http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/, if you don't mind another library

Comment: @Firedrake969. How about a pure JavaScript solution?

Comment: Jquery is fine.  Jet don't want a separate library.

Comment: Why don't you just wrap your source/flag changing logic into a function that can be called from anywhere you need it?

Comment: @NormanBreau  Do you mean just some function that set's a flag right before I change the iframe src?  Isn't that the same as directly setting some variable?

Comment: I have no idea how your code is organized, so its hard to provide an example, but if you want to change the `src` of your iframe, I would create a function like `setMyIframeSource(src);` that sets your flag and changes the `src` attribute of your iframe. This seems like simpler solution to me. But if you really watch to dispatch your own events, you could take a look at `CustomEvents`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events